# How to share a test across multiple specs in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm using Protractor to test an Angular app. There is a generic share functionality which runs across various different pages - at the moment I have the test in each individual spec for each page, however now looking into optimisation, I would quite like to make this as DRY as possible.

What is the best practice in getting something like this in place, or is this indeed bad practice and I should be keeping the test in each individual spec.

I am using Page Objects for each spec - however this falls into the same issue as I have a 1:1 relationship with Page Object -> Spec.

Any thoughts welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty simple in the end, just create a module export of any common suites, require it and use it :)

See link - http://pavelbogomolenko.github.io/dry-principles-with-protractor.html